# What is the word for music that is both a capella and instrumental?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, music

Now, I know the terms "[a capella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_cappella)" and "instrumental" are pretty incompatible, and to tell the truth, something like "Lyric-less" would fit better than "instrumental" in this case. Basically, I'm looking for a word that applies to songs that use the human voice more for the purposes of making notes than singing words, perhaps even imitating conventional instruments like violins or guitars (but not drums, I know the term for that: beatboxing).

For instance, I want a word that could be used (for example) in place of my made-up word "Accapellental" in this example sentence:

> Smoove McGroove is a great Accapellental artist.

Comment: I think the answer is vocalization / vocalisation. But I also think this may be a duplicate question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130010/using-your-voice-as-an-instrument

Comment: @Bread, not quite (especially since the answers on that question are extremely unsatisfying... _sigh_ it looks like a new word needs to be coined, or I'll have to ask Smoove McGroove himself).

Comment: I think you have defined some words incorrectly. From wikipedia: "Vocal music is a type of music performed by one or more singers, either with instrumental accompaniment, or without instrumental accompaniment (a cappella), in which singing provides the main focus of the piece. Music which employs singing but does not feature it prominently is generally considered instrumental music (e.g. the wordless women's choir in the final movement of Holst's The Planets) as is music without singing. Music without any non-vocal instrumental accompaniment is referred to as a cappella."

Comment: Very similar (but not quite a duplicate, and on our sister site): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103178/what-would-you-call-this-type-of-song/103192#103192

Comment: You wouldn't want to distinguish between the imitation of the sounds produced by existing instruments and use of the human voice as an instrument in its own right?

Comment: No because imitation of instrumental sounds has from the first and always been part and parcel to a capella, being, in fact, in the way of the [choir of the] [Sistine] chapel. Indeed the choir of the grandest of chapels of Medieval times would sing many a song, some lyrical, others not. But the one thing they did not use: musical instruments. Today, that's all "a capella" means to the vast majority of people: "without instrumental accompaniment". Yes, I frankly disagree with the accepted answer below. But it is now 2023 and was then 2018. What's a person to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *a cappella* group ***Naturally 7*** calls this ***vocal play***.

From their [Wikipedia page*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturally_7):

> Naturally 7 is an American music group with a distinct a cappella style they call "***vocal play***," which, according to group leader Roger Thomas, is "***the art of becoming an instrument using the human voice to create the sound.***" They simulate the sounds of an instrumental band using only their voices, mouths and distortion effects. The group was formed in 1999 in New York City. It currently consists of the Thomas brothers Roger (musical director, arranger, first baritone, rapping) and Warren (drums, guitar, third tenor), Rod Eldridge (first tenor, scratching, trumpet), Rickey Cort (fourth tenor, guitar), Dwight Stewart (second baritone, vocals, trombone), Garfield Buckley (second tenor, harmonica), and Kelvin "Kelz" Mitchel (bass guitar, trumpet).

<sup><sub>* *emphasis mine*</sub></sup>

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5MkNOXSdkA) is one of their videos where they demonstrate their skills.  At the end they even include their definition.
[image: Vocal Play definition]

Answer (score 1):

Listen to [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fW630zFA93Y)
This is obviously an instrumental piece, with the human voice one of the instruments.

> "What need is there of words, when you will be able to convey everything better and more expressively than anyone could with words by your voice and interpretation?”

were words by the composer, Sergei Rachmaninoff, who composed the cited work, explaining the use of a single syllable in the [voice](https://pages.stolaf.edu/music242-spring2014/portfolio/trapping-a-melodic-line-rachmaninoffs-melancholy-vocalise/).

Obviously, this cited work represents only one sort of voice and instrument music. Other specific types have established names. One word will probably never serve to describe the various uses of the human voice inter-playing with other instruments.

Fabricating a single word to fit all situations might be the best way to  get a single word solution.
I would be interested if such a word took hold.

Comment: Should anyone doubt this is an instrumental work, the Rachmaninoff, here is the same with 'cello, rather than human voice    ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C24n9izmVA